# Is it possible to calculate the sum of a whole row?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a file that doesn't have a fixed number of columns.
I was wondering if there is a way to tell excel to put the sum of this row in a specific cell, in a way that each time a column is added to the file I don't have to update the formula and increase the range of the sum.

p.s.
I know I can make it a bit easier by just updating the formula like once in 10 times or so. But I was wondering if it's possible to do it once in a lifetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your formula will be in b1, and you want to sum from C1 to the end, then simply:

```
B1:  =SUM(C1:XFD1)
```

Replace `XFD` with whatever column you think will be far enough to the right that you'll never have to adjust the formula; or leave it as is.

You could make the range dynamic, with something like:

```
B1:  =SUM(OFFSET($A1,0,2,1,LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER(1:1),COLUMN(1:1))-2))
```

but since that formula is volatile, it may add excessive time to the calculations.

Answer (score 5):

Yes `sum(1:1)` will sum up all values within the first row.

Keep in mind this does not work if the sum needs to be stored in the same row. As you would create a circularity problem.

Comment: the second column should be the sum and from the 3rd column on should be included. but thanks:) i didn't know that either that's also quite useful:)

Comment: Under that condition I'd say Ron Rosenfelds answers should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

- First: Take note of your first cell (Assumed A1)
- Second: Take note of your farthest cell (Assumed AZ1)

Then:

```
=sum(A1:AZ1)
```